# Applying functions to differently formatted files within a folder

Tags: matlab, if-statement, file-io, formatting

I have a folder filled with files. The leftmost column of each file is dates. Some of the files have `yyyymmdd`  dates, and others have `mm/dd/yyyy` dates. I want to apply a function `minutebars1()` to the `yyyymmdd` type, and a function `minutebars2()` to the `mm/dd/yyyy` type. I tried to do this with an if statement, attempting to say that, within a for loop going through all files, if textscan reads successfully with a given format, then apply the correct function. However the code as posted below does not work, giving me an error `Badly formed format string` for the textscan lines. How should this be done correctly?

```
% reads all file names
fPath = uigetdir('.', 'Select directory containing CSV files');
if fPath==0, error('no folder selected'), end
fNames = dir( fullfile(fPath,'*.csv') );
fNames = strcat(fPath, filesep, {fNames.name});

% process each file
for i=1:length(fNames)

    fid = fopen(fNames{i},'rt');

    if   textscan(fid, '%i,%d:%d:%*d.%*d,%f,%d,%*c') % minutebars1() for format 1
    minutebars1(fNames{i});
    end

    if   textscan(fid, '%d/%d/%d,%d:%d:%d,%f,%d,%*c') % minutebars2() for format 2
    minutebars2t(fNames{i});
    end

    fclose(fid);

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the first line as a string, and test which format it's in.  `fgetl` for reading a single line, and `regexp` for pattern testing.

```
% Get first line of file
fid = fopen(fnames{i}, 'rt');
str = fgetl(fid);
fclose(fid);

% test for pattern mm/dd/yyyy
if(regexp(str, '\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d'))
    minutebars2(fNames{i});
else
    minutebars1(fNames{i});
end
```